# how to get javascript variable into URL.Action mvc method

Tags: url.action

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
   document.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditEncounter", "EditEncounter", new { encounterId = "'<%:id%>'", popId = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })'
                            //new { encounterId = temp.EncounterId, popId = (int)TempData["POPULATIONID"] }
}
```

How in sam hill do I get that id variable into my Url.Action method?

This is what I am looking at when I debugg

```
document.location.href = '/EditEncounter/EditEncounter?encounterId=%40id&amp;popId=2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dummyURL ='@Url.Action("EditEncounter", "EditEncounter", new { encounterId = -2, popId = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })';
                            var path =dummyURL.replace("-2", id);
                            debugger;
                            document.location.href = path;
```

That appears to work.